# @JmsListener usage for publish-subscribe topic

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I am trying to create example for publish-subscribe based on @JmsListener annotation: https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/05-jms/0515-publish-subscribe

Relevant code snippets:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class JmsPublishSubscribeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(JmsPublishSubscribeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQTopic simpleTopic() {
        return new ActiveMQTopic("simpleTopic");
    }

}

@Component
public class SimpleMessageListener1 {

    @JmsListener(destination = "simpleTopic")
    public void readMessage(String message) {
      //....
    }

}

@Component
public class SimpleMessageListener2 {

    @JmsListener(destination = "simpleTopic")
    public void readMessage(String message) {
      //....
    }

}
```

The problem is that is get this behaviour:

```
2015-05-17 20:07:04.985  INFO 22983 --- [pool-1-thread-1] n.l.b.e.chapter05.SimpleMessageSender    : Sending message: simple message
2015-05-17 20:07:05.070  INFO 22983 --- [enerContainer-1] n.l.b.e.c.JmsPublishSubscribeApplication : Message Received: simple message via listener 2
2015-05-17 20:07:05.975  INFO 22983 --- [pool-1-thread-1] n.l.b.e.chapter05.SimpleMessageSender    : Sending message: simple message
2015-05-17 20:07:05.986  INFO 22983 --- [enerContainer-1] n.l.b.e.c.JmsPublishSubscribeApplication : Message Received: simple message via listener 1
2015-05-17 20:07:06.975  INFO 22983 --- [pool-1-thread-1] n.l.b.e.chapter05.SimpleMessageSender    : Sending message: simple message
2015-05-17 20:07:06.987  INFO 22983 --- [enerContainer-1] n.l.b.e.c.JmsPublishSubscribeApplication : Message Received: simple message via listener 2
2015-05-17 20:07:07.975  INFO 22983 --- [pool-1-thread-1] n.l.b.e.chapter05.SimpleMessageSender    : Sending message: simple message
2015-05-17 20:07:07.994  INFO 22983 --- [enerContainer-1] n.l.b.e.c.JmsPublishSubscribeApplication : Message Received: simple message via listener 1
```

But each message should be consumed by both listeners by definition of topics. What am I missing?

Comment: Add an `application.properties` and set `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain` to `true`.

Comment: Can confirm that this flag works. Strange that it doesn't work when you do it programatically: jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);

Comment: @M.Deinum Don't you want to create an answer to earn some points?

Comment: It also works programmatically but not with a `JmsTemplate` as that isn't used by `@JmsListener`. You would have to register a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` named `jmsListenerContainer` and set that property to `true`. However it is easier to simply add that configuration parameter.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When using a `@JmsListener` it uses a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which extends [`JmsDestinationAccessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/jms/support/destination/JmsDestinationAccessor.html) which by default has the `pubSubDomain` set to `false`. When this property is false it is operating on a queue. If you want to use topics you have to set this properties value to `true`.

As you are using [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-using-jms-receiving) you can quite easily set this property to true by adding the `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain` property to the `application.properties` and set it to `true`.

```
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
```

When using a [`@JmsListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) it is looking for a `jmsListenerContainerFactory` named bean, if that isn't available a default one is expected. You can also include your own bean and programmatically set this property yo `true`.

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory dmlc = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    dmlc.setPubSubDomain(true);
    // Other configuration here
    return dmlc;
}
```

This would of course also work but would be more work, more information on this can be found in the documentation of the [`@EnableJms` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/EnableJms.html).

Comment: @M. Deinum your advice doesn;t work for me but advice of **ldz** works

Comment: Bean named 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer'

Comment: yes, it should be `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` not just `DefaultJmsListenerContainer`

Answer (score 10):

Switching the default destination type of a `@JmsListener` from `Queue` to `Topic` can be done completely in Java without modifying the properties or using XML.

The [Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms) contains an example for customizing the default settings provided by `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

It requires defining a custom bean like follows:

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

This can then be used in the `@JmsListener` annotated method:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: I want to have the parameters destination and containerFactory as non constant fields. How can I achieve that using annotations? Please help

Comment: @DhirajGandhi you can do something like this:  
    `@JmsListener(destination = "${async.jms.queue.name}", ...`

Comment: I prefer this solution in case you want to listen both to queues and topics.